# Tailwind mixed classes with utility classes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

Is there a chance I can mix using Tailwind's utility (inline) classes with the JavaScript `styles`/`classes` module?

```js
<div className={ classes.preference }>
```

together with:

```js
<div className="bg-grey-light h-screen">
```

Comment: Didn't find the answer on the internet, so excuse if duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literals to concatenate constants and variables.

Example:

```
<div className={`bg-grey-light h-screen ${classes.preference}`}>
  ...
</div>
```